# Compiler complain about ''*** glibc detected *** ./myprog: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001cd6240 *** ''

Tags: c

I have this function :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

typedef struct adress Adress;

struct adress {char *num; char *street; char *namestreet; char *city; char *postal;};

int main(void) {

    int n = 0;

    int i;

    struct adress *Adress;

    FILE *f = fopen("/home/file.txt","r");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Impossible to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line,256,f)) {
        if (n == 0) {
            Adress = malloc(sizeof(struct adress)*(n+1));
        }
        Adress[n].num = malloc( 256*sizeof( char));

        Adress[n].street = malloc( 256*sizeof( char));

        Adress[n].namestreet = malloc( 256*sizeof( char));

        Adress[n].city = malloc( 256*sizeof( char));

        Adress[n].postal = malloc( 256*sizeof( char));

        fscanf( f , "%s %s %s %s %s", Adress[n].num, Adress[n].street, Adress[n].namestreet, Adress[n].city ,Adress[n].postal);

        n++;  
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nNum : %s \n", Adress[i].num);
        printf("\nStreet : %s \n", Adress[i].street);
        printf("\nStreet Name :%s \n", Adress[i].namestreet);
        printf("\nCity :%s \n", Adress[i].city);
        printf("\nPostal Code : %s \n", Adress[i].postal);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile my program I get the following errors:

> *** glibc detected *** ./myprog: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001cd6240

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Has anyone gotten this type of error before?

Comment: It is quite confusing to use the same identifier `Adress` for both the typedef and the name of the local array pointer.

Comment: `Adress` has only one element by `Adress = malloc(sizeof(struct adress)*(n+1));`.

Comment: just to clarify, it is not the compiler that gives that output but your program.

Comment: What can i do to result the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You only allocate enough space for one `struct adress`, if you read more than one line, you will write beyond the end of the array pointed to by `Adress` and corrupt the heap.  A subsequent call to `malloc` detects this and aborts with the message: `./myprog: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001cd6240`.

Initiliaze `Adress` to `NULL`:

```
    struct adress *Adress = NULL;
```

and change these 3 lines:

```
    if (n == 0) {
        Adress = malloc(sizeof(struct adress)*(n+1));
    }
```

to

```
    Adress = realloc(Adress, sizeof(struct adress)*(n+1));
    if (!Adress) {
         printf("out of memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your program is buggy and corrupted the libc linked list that handle your memory.

The lib c has 'private' data stored in the hunk of memory you allocated.

usually there is a header like:

```
struct hdr
{
  size_t size;                  /* Exact size requested by user.  */
  unsigned long int magic;      /* Magic number to check header integrity.  */
  struct hdr *prev;
  struct hdr *next;
  __ptr_t block;                /* Real block allocated, for memalign.  */
  unsigned long int magic2;     /* Extra, keeps us doubleword aligned.  */
};
```

if one of the magic is corrupted by a buffer overflow in your code, you get such errors (as the libc can figure out that its structures were corrupted)

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to confuse the OP even more.  The heap management internals are beyond the scope of this question.  Helping the OP find the offending code is more useful.

Comment: Thank you so much ;) Now the programm have not errors but when i put three o for adress in my file, i have just two adress in the output. Why ??